# Installing external libraries on worker nodes in Pyspark-Cluster mode

Tags: python, hadoop, nlp, apache-spark, textblob

I am working on pyspark for NLP processing etc.  I am using TextBlob Python library.

Normally, in standalone mode, it is easy to install the external Python libraries.  In cluster mode I am facing problem to install these libraries on worker nodes remotely.  I cannot access each worker machine to install these libs in Python path.

I tried to use Sparkcontext pyfiles option to ship `.zip` files...but the problem is these Python packages need to be installed on worker machines.

Are there different ways of doing it so that this lib-Textblob could be available in Python path?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use Sparkcontext pyfiles option to ship .zip files...but the problem is these Python packages needs to be get installed on worker machines.

I guess you use defautl URL schema(local:)
**local:** - a URI starting with local:/ is expected to exist as a local file on each worker node. This means that no network IO will be incurred, and works well for large files/JARs that are pushed to each worker, or shared via NFS, GlusterFS, etc

Another URL schema is **file:**, every executor pulls the file from the driver HTTP server automatically, then you don't need to installed them on worker machines.
file: - Absolute paths and file:/ URIs are served by the driver’s HTTP file server, and every executor pulls the file from the driver HTTP server.

please refer to 
[Submitting Applications - Advanced Dependency Management](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)